# Simulate capacitive touch

Tags: arduino, capacitive, touchscreen

I am using an Arduino Uno and would like to simulate a capacitive tap with zero human contact on my iPhone 5 screen.

What seems to work right now is putting a coin on the screen and connecting the coin to a power source (such as Digital I/O Pin) and when voltage is sent to the coin it triggers a "tap" on the screen.  Is this safe?  Is there a better way to do this?  I just read somewhere else that any grounded conductive object should work.  Is it better to ground the coin or to connect it to a power source?  Also, how can I stop sending current to/grounding the coin so the simulated touch is stopped.  Right now, I can't get the arduino to stop "touching" the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used to work in touchscreen development, we had a couple of methods to achieve exactly that. The first was to interrupt the connection to ground with a miniaturised relay. The shorter connection between the relay and the "finger" the better.
The other method was to use an RC servo, which simulated a mechanical finger.
Both worked, but obviously the relay was faster acting.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a miniaturized relay I could use?  Would this work: https://www.amazon.com/WINGONEER-KY-019-Channel-Module-arduino/dp/B06XHJ2PBJ/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=relay&qid=1550879171&s=gateway&sr=8-5

Comment: Or this: https://www.amazon.com/Tolako-Arduino-Indicator-Channel-Official/dp/B00VRUAHLE/ref=sr_1_18?keywords=5v+relay&qid=1550880852&s=gateway&sr=8-18#customerReviews (I think they're the same thing, just this one has better reviews)

Comment: pretty much any of the Omron G6K would work, but all you reall yneed is just a small relay. https://www.digikey.no/products/en/relays/signal-relays-up-to-2-amps/189?k=relay&k=&pkeyword=relay&sv=0&s=5886&sf=0&FV=1c0002%2C1c0008%2Ca8c0007%2C1f140000%2Cffe000bd&quantity=&ColumnSort=1410&page=1&pageSize=25

Comment: This might work in some cases, but it is not a general solution.  At the least, if you are going to use a servo, use a touch stylus determined to work with the target screen.

Comment: Test environments use a small surface area metallic probe with a small reed relay to do this. It's very common. I've seen both multiple fixed position probes and 2D positioning systems used (no Z involved). Typically the 2D positioning is used where you need to emulate screen swipes.