# Test device for capacitive touch screens?

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen, test-equipment

Are there any (more or less) simple test devices for capacitive touch screens,
e.g. something which I can attach to a touch screen and which is able to do capacitive inputs at fixed locations (ideally, it contains a matrix of such locations)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulate capacitive touch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423740/simulate-capacitive-touch)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough to be sure but I suspect that any matrix you put across the screen will cause stray capacitance problems and make it very difficult to know what exactly you have tested. A much more definitive test could be done with one of those flexible rubber topped capacitive touch-screen stylus pens and a robot or 3-axis pen holder. It should be reasonably straight forward to modify a cheap 3D printer to a 3-axis CNC. Replace the extruder with a pen holder, figure out a few G-codes and you can automate your tests quite realistically.

[image]

*[Tappy](https://www.testdevlab.com/blog/2017/07/how-we-built-a-robot-for-automated-manual-mobile-testing/) might give you some good ideas.*

I expect that with this method you could easily check sensitivity by monitoring the Z-axis value that is registered as a touch on the display. All sorts of possibilities are then opened up such as giving a "heat map" of the sensitivity of the various test points, etc.